# How can I fix this issue where Google Maps div map_canvas is shifted to the right in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-maps

I'm creating a website where on the contacts page, the map view (map_canvas div) will take all the available space left in the browser's viewport.

Als when a user resizes the window everything gets updated.
This works very well in Chrome, IE, Safari but not in Firefox...

I noticed that when I remove the (automatically generated style attribute by google's api) style attribute overflow:hidden, the map view is displayed correctly.

There are no margins or paddings.

I really hope someone can help me out here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding float:left to #map_canvas seems to make it display correctly in Firefox.

However, it seems there are some issues with the resizeStuff function you might have to check out. Chrome console is throwing this error when resizing the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'gmap' resizeStuff
```

Comment: Yes I noticed the issue in the console, it appears to be working correctly though...

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT problem:

```
    <style type="text/css">
      @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        div #map_canvas {
          left: -350px;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

This will apply the canvas fix only in FF. Change the left:-350px to whatever your map width is.